# HP Printer problem

Tags: printing, hp

Some of you may have seen some of my previous posts about my System76 laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS not printing to an HP OfficeJet Pro 6978. Today I had an interesting observation. I had gotten messages on boot that one of my partitions was low. So I booted from an old (18.04) Ubuntu CD so I could use the partition manager (Gparted) on it to rearrange some of the partitions. After that just for fun, I tried to print a file with the text editor on the CD. It found the printer, identified it correctly and printed just fine. The print manager on my hard drive identifies the printer, but when I try to print anything it says it can't find a printer on the network. Is there any way I can install the print manager from the old Ubuntu on the CD to my hard drive so it will print? Or should I just install the old Ubuntu and stick with that?

Comment: You've somewhat void on details. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (assuming desktop) has had 6 ISOs produced providing stacks based on 4.15 (GA), 4.18, 5.0, 5.3, 5.4 (last four being HWE) but you didn't say which worked; if it was the last HWE (5.4) then it would be the same stack as Ubuntu 20.04 using the GA stack (desktop has moved to 5.8 currently depending on choices & how installed). The *focal* system besides me (20.04.2) is using the 5.4 (GA) kernel meaning it'll be the same stack as a 18.04.5 *live* system; but you didn't say what you're using (20.04) & what you tried (18.04?)

Comment: Also note there are some issues with LibreOffice printing in 20.04 when using Qt5 in your stack ; so if it's 20.04 and libreoffice I'd check it's not that bug (which doesn't impact many Ubuntu 20.04 systems which default to the GTK3 stack).